# How to add up hours, mins, seconds in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have code that will get a column with different durations in it. The format is "hh:mm:ss". I need to add all of these up (which will exceed 24 hours) and get a total at the end in the same format. Is there a way to do this in VBA?

```
standbyTime = CDate(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(dateCell.Row, "U").Value)
failureTime = CDate(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(dateCell.Row, "W").Value)
powerOffTime = CDate(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(dateCell.Row, "X").Value)
                        
If (ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(dateCell.Row, "W").Value <> "") Then
   operationalTime = TimeValue(failureTime) - TimeValue(standbyTime)
Else
   operationalTime = TimeValue(powerOffTime) - TimeValue(standbyTime)
End If
                        
totalTime = totalTime + operationalTime
```

This code will roll over the time.

The output will need to look like 100:35:20

Any ideas?

Comment: `The format is "hh:mm:ss"` - well, make it `[hh]:mm:ss`.

Comment: @GSerg that's a great tip! For reference, using this format you can just sum all the time values in the spreadsheet and set the output field with this so no VBA needed.

Comment: @GSerg How would I add the times up before formatting? It doesn't seem like it is working as expected. Should I format each time to that before doing the addition?

Comment: @Tragamor There is some other code in there that is easier (for me) to do in VBA instead of as a formula

Comment: Just like you add them up now, as dates. (Not that you are doing it correctly in your code, you will get wrong results if the dates belong to different days.)

Answer (score -1):

An Example:

[image]

Imagine you have these values in the cells then the code would be:

```
Sub SumTimes()
Dim d As Double
Dim w As Worksheet
Set w = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
d = w.Range("b2").Value2 + w.Range("b3").Value2 + w.Range("b4").Value2 ' be aware of value2
Dim h As Long, m As Long, s As Long
h = Fix(d * 24) ' hours
m = Fix(d * 1440) - h * 60 ' Minutes
s = Fix(d * 86400) - h * 3600 - m * 60 ' Seconds

MsgBox h & ":" & m & ":" & s

End Sub
```

Make sure to use Value2